# How to get ps to print group?

Tags: linux, bash, ps

`ps aux` will print out something formatted according to the below. It shows the user that the process runs under. But is there a way to display the group that the process runs under?

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can specify the desired format:

```
   o format
          Specify user-defined format.  Identical to -o and --format.
```

For example, saying:

```
ps o pid,group
```

would print `pid` and `group`.

Saying:

```
ps o pid,group,gid
```

would print `pid`, `group` and `group ID`.

---

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236582/how-to-get-ps-to-print-group/20236633?noredirect=1#comment30213790_20236633), the following might work for you:

```
ps o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,comm,group,gid
```

To see all processes:

```
ps ax o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,comm,group,gid
```

Comment: How do I get the group added to the print out of all the columns shown in `ps aux`? Everything I've tried seems to give a format error curiously.

Comment: But now I can't get it to print out all processes!

Comment: @user782220 Insert `ax` before the output format.  Added in the edit above.

Comment: For printing out supplementary group names, add `supgrp`.

Comment: I also prefer `cmd` as the last option instead of `comm` for full command line.

Comment: Nor `cmd` nor `comm` prints full command on Ubuntu 18.04. Any suggestions how to make it print full command?

Answer (score 2):

This gives similar output to `ps -ef` but adds the effective group name.

```sh
ps -eO user,group,ppid,c,start_time
```

(That flag is a capital O.)

Answer (score 1):

```
ps ax o user,pid,group,gid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,comm,args=ARGS
```

To print the full command e.g python script.py --env LOCAL